# User does not have create table permissions error message

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the error

> Client HTTP request failed: User does not have create table permissions

when running an application that connects to a MS SQL Server and needs to load data into tables that need to be created.

How do I provide the user the required permissions to these tables in the SQL Server 2016 Management Studio?

Answer (score 0):

To *Grant permission* to `create` a `table` in a database you need two permissions

1.To `Alter` the `schema`

Before granting Create table permission to a user, the user should have Alter schema permission

```
GRANT ALTER ON Schema :: [schemaname] TO [username]
```

2.To `Create` the table

```
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO [username]
```

**Note :** If your table structure is fixed then you can create a table in prior and load the data instead of creating table everytime